# Does UIView's -drawRect: have to be called on the main thread?

Tags: iphone, ios, uiview

Does UIView's `-drawRect:` method have to be drawn on the main thread or can CADisplayLink call `-setNeedsDisplay` on a custom view in a different run loop?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All UIKit calls should be done on the main thread.

Comment: As I explain in my answer, as of iOS 4.0 you can indeed draw to a UIView within a background thread.

Answer (score 10):

[As of iOS 4.0](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#releasenotes/General/WhatsNewIniPhoneOS/Articles/iPhoneOS4.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009559-SW29), you can draw within a UIView's `-drawRect:` on a background thread:

> - Drawing to a graphics context in UIKit is now thread-safe. Specifically:
>
>   - The routines used to access and manipulate the graphics context can now correctly handle contexts residing on different threads.
>   - String and image drawing is now thread-safe.
>   - Using color and font objects in multiple threads is now safe to do.

See also their comments in [Technical Q&A QA1637](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1637/_index.html) regarding this in iOS 4.0.

Any version of iOS before that still needs to have this drawing be on the main thread.